# Are there any UTF-8 code units that have byte 60 or 62 (`<` and `>`) as not the first byte of their binary representation?

Tags: unicode, utf-8

I need to debug a XML parser and I am wondering if I can construct "malicious" input that will cause it to not recognize opening and closing tags correctly.

Additionally, where can I find this sort of information in general? After this I will also want to be sure that the parser I am working with won't have trouble with other special characters such as `&`, `=` , `"`, etc.

Comment: The term "UTF-8 codepoint" makes no sense.

Comment: @KerrekSB Of course it makes no sense. If I knew the correct terms I would probably know how to have gotten an answer already :)

Comment: Yeah, that's probably true! The correct term is "code unit". A code point, by contrast, is an abstract value which you are trying to *encode*. You can find information about this [on the internet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UTF-8 makes it very easy to figure out what the role of a code unit (i.e. a byte) is:

- If the highest bit is not set, i.e. the code unit is `0xxxxxxx`, then this is byte expresses an entire code point, whose value is `xxxxxxx` (i.e. 7 bits of information).
- If the highest bit is set and the code unit is `10xxxxxx`, then it is a continuation part of a multibyte sequence, carrying six bits of information.
- Otherwise, the code unit is the initial byte of a multibyte sequence, as follows:

  - `110xxxxx`: Two bytes (one continuation byte), for 5 + 6 = 11 bits.
  - `1110xxxx`: Three bytes (two continuation bytes), for 4 + 6 + 6 = 16 bits.
  - `11110xxx`: Four bytes (three continuation bytes), for 3 + 6 + 6 + 6 = 21 bits.

As you can see, a value 60, which is `00111100`, is a single-byte codepoint of value `60`, and the same byte cannot occur as part of any multibyte sequence.

The scheme can actually be extended up to seven bytes, encoding up to 36 bits, but since Unicode only requires 21 bits, four bytes suffice. The standard mandates that a code point *must* be represented with the minimal number of code units.

*Update:* As @Mark Tolonen rightly points out, you should check carefully whether each encoded code point is actually encoded with the minimal number of code units. If a browser would inadvertently accept such input, a user could sneak something past you that you would not spot in a byte-for-byte analysis. As a starting point you could look for bytes like `10111100`, but you'd have to check the entire multibyte sequence of which it is a part (since it can of course occur legitimately as a part of different code points). Ultimately, if you can't trust the browser, you don't really get around decoding everything and just check­ing the resulting code point sequence for occurrences of U+3C etc., and don't even bother looking at the byte stream.

Answer (score 1):

In UTF-8, no. In other encodings, yes.

In UTF-8, by design, all bytes of a multibyte character will always have the highest bit set. Vice versa, a byte that doesn't have the highest bit set is always an ASCII character.

However, this is not true for other encodings, which are also valid for XML.

For more information about UTF-8, check e.g [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

Answer (score 1):

A poorly-designed UTF-8 decoder *could* interpret the bytes `C0 BC` and `C0 BE` as `U+003C` and `U+003E`.  As @KerrekSB stated in his answer:

> The standard mandates that a code point *must* be represented with the minimal number of code units.

But a poor algorithm might still decode a malformed two-byte UTF-8 sequence that is *not* the minimal number of code units:

> C0 BC = **110**00000 **10**111100 = 00000111100 = 3C<sub>hex</sub> = 60<sub>dec</sub> = '<'

So in your testing be sure to include malformed UTF-8 sequences and verify that they are rejected.

Comment: Just to be clear: even if you misrepresent a small value with a large multi-byte sequence, you still won't get the literal value 60 for any byte in the sequence, though.

Comment: Right, but you could get a Unicode 60 codepoint, which matters if the XML parsing occurs after the UTF-8 decoding.

Comment: Yes, that's a good point (and I wonder whether any browsers allow that). I notice now that there's a discrepancy between the question's title and body.

Comment: I wonder what the pros and cons would have been of specifying that the range of codes represented using any length coding will be offset by the number of codes that were representable with the shorter coding, so 0x880 (rather than 0x800) codes could be represented with two bytes, 0x10880 codes with three bytes, etc.)  Under such a scheme, the "redundant" and forbidden encodings would be used to increase the number of values representable with any given length.